# "ellipse" element created through JS doesn't appear in html

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm new to svg. What i'm trying to do is to create an ellipse element with JS and append it to the SVG tag. The HTML code is

```html
<svg width="640" height="480">
  
<ellipse  cx="200" cy="100" rx="90" ry="60" stroke-width="10" stroke="orange" fill="none" opacity="0.6"/>
  
  <ellipse  cx="200" cy="100" rx="70" ry="40" stroke-width="10" stroke="green" fill="none" opacity="0.6"/>
  
</svg>
```

Below is the JS code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    var el=document.createElement('ellipse');

    $(el).attr("cx",300);
    $(el).attr("cy",200);
    $(el).attr("stroke","red");
    $(el).attr("stroke-width","10");
    $(el).attr("fill","green");
    $(el).attr("rx",120);
    $(el).attr("ry",80);
 
    $("svg").append(el);

</script>
```

But the ellipse didn't appear on the viewport ,but when i inspect HTML  i found the ellipse element that i created is appended to SVG.  what makes the difference  when created this way & what is the correct approach to dynamically  add elements to SVG

FYI see the image below
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a custom HTML element instead of an SVG element. Use `createElementNS` to create the SVG element:

```js
$(function(){

  var el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'ellipse');

  el.setAttribute('cx', 300);
  el.setAttribute('cy', 200);
  el.setAttribute('stroke', "red");
  el.setAttribute('stroke-width', 10);
  el.setAttribute('fill', "green");
  el.setAttribute('rx', 120);
  el.setAttribute('ry', 80);

  $("svg").append(el);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="640" height="480">
  
<ellipse  cx="200" cy="100" rx="90" ry="60" stroke-width="10" stroke="orange" fill="none" opacity="0.6"/>
  
  <ellipse  cx="200" cy="100" rx="70" ry="40" stroke-width="10" stroke="green" fill="none" opacity="0.6"/>
  
</svg>
```